# Java get tag name of a Node

Tags: java, xml

I need to read a small xml file and validate it's content against a hardcoded HashMap with key= tag and value= text inside tag.
I can not get the tag name of the Node.
If I convert the Node to Element I get a cast exception.

I am reading using the DOOM classes:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

        NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("MergeOptions");
        if (list.getLength() == 0)
        {
        //throw
        }
        NodeList config = list.item(0).getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i <= config.getLength() - 1; i++)
        {

            Node setting = config.item(i);
            String nodeName = setting.getNodeValue();
            String value = setting.getTextContent();
            if (defaultMergeOptions.containsKey(nodeName) == false)
            {
                    //throw
            }

            if (defaultMergeOptions.get(nodeName).equals(value))
            {
                    //throw
            }
```

Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <MergeOptions>
   <sometagName>false</sometagName>
 </MergeOptions>
```

Comment: What is `defaultMergeOptions` ?

Comment: the HashMap a validate the xml against. It has as keys all the tags that the xml should have and as values it has all the correct values for the xml tags

Comment: Add that HashMap in the code and edit the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I am helping you with the following code structure. Once you see the tag name and the value, you can apply the logic to compare from HashMap key or value.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xmlFile = "test.xml";
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        System.out.println(root.getNodeName());

        NodeList list = root.getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = list.item(i);
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
             {
                System.out.println(node.getNodeName() + " : " + node.getTextContent());
             }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to run your code, it works fine, no class cast exceptions.
Note how I used the element in the for loop the get the name, value or the existsnce of a possible children.

```
final String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n" +
            "<MergeOptions>\n<sometagName>false</sometagName>\n</MergeOptions>";

final InputStream xsmlStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());

final DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
final DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
final Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xsmlStream);

final NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("MergeOptions");

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    final Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
    System.out.println(element.hasChildNodes());
    System.out.println(element.getNodeValue());
    System.out.println(element.getTagName());
}
```

Using hash map is with node names as keys is a bit tricky, 'cause if your XML file have multiple node names with same names and different values, the HashMap will only store only one unique keys thus validate only one of the same name nodes. The other same name nodes but with different values will be not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Well I did something diffrent.

Seems to work:

```
IntegrationTest.getInstance().getLogger().log(Level.INFO, "Reading merge-que file: " + xmlFile.getAbsolutePath());
    try
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

        for (Entry<String, String> entry : defaultMergeOptions.entrySet())
        {
            String tagName = entry.getKey();

            NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
            if (list.getLength() != 1)
            {
                IntegrationTest.getInstance().getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, TestResult.FAIL, "Merge option [{0}] has invalid content. Tag [{1}] missing or to many",
                        new Object[] { xmlFile.getName(), tagName });
                result = TestResult.FAIL;
                continue;
            }

            if (!defaultMergeOptions.get(tagName).equals(list.item(0).getTextContent()))
            {
                IntegrationTest.getInstance().getLogger().log(Level.WARNING, TestResult.FAIL, "Merge option [{0}] has diffrent content for tag [{1}].",
                        new Object[] { xmlFile.getCanonicalPath(), tagName });
                result = TestResult.FAIL;
            }

        }



    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        IntegrationTest.getInstance().getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, SBUtil.stackTraceToString(e.getStackTrace()));
        throw new IntegrationTestException(e);

    }
}
```